# Google Maps Android - Without any code changes the map in my two applications stopped working. Did Google screw something up in the last few hours?

Tags: android, google-maps

Even though I made no changes to my code the google map still stopped working. Now I can't make it work no matter what I try. Please note that both apps were fully functional and runnable before this incident.

At the moment all I'm getting from Google is a grey screen with the 'Google' text on the lower left corner. So I'm sure the map still sort of works. Also hitting the Google server for location queries also crashes the app ( URL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + search + "&sensor=false"; ...and so forth...).

So what's up? Did google screw something up? Does anyone else have this problem? The official Google Maps App does work fine for me. I checked the API panel and everything seems to be just fine. I even made new API keys for both apps but they don't work either. Can someone shed some light on the situation? Maybe I'm just missing something, but either way this is really bad for me.

Is it Google or is it me? The query problem seems to indicate that the problem is on Google's side.

Comment: My friend's Picasa site is also down, so I'm pretty sure it's Google. Damn them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you updated your `google-play-service` from the `SDK Manager` to `revision 13`, then there is a new `meta-data` tag you need to add in your application's `Manifest` file:

```
<meta-data
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

without it your application will crash. Place it right next to your `Google Map API key` `meta-data` tag.

Comment: I'm quite certain that I didn't update it, but I'll give it a check tomorrow. Thank you for answering.

Comment: This was pretty close to the actual problem. I indeed had updated my SDK. But using Xamarin I had not updated the Google Play Services Component. Actually there is no new version of the Component so I had to downgrade the SDK to rev12 for the time being. I'll mark this as the right answer, since you did point me to the right direction + i wouldn't have known this in the future anyways. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not using Xamarin, But I'm glad you have solved your problem.

Comment: Well usually the problems are common since it's the android libraries that cause them. Just gotta know where to look.